# Why do I keep dying in 'Hangar 18 1/2'?

Tags: saints-row-the-third

I'm on the Hangar 18 1/2 mission in Saints Row 3 and in the final part, when I have to destroy the generator (after protecting Kwilanna), instead of the generator exploding, and me being temporarily stunned on the ground with shock (as I've seen in YouTube videos), the generator explodes, but I die almost instantly and hence fail the mission.

Is there a way that I can avoid this?

Thanks

Comment: Have you maxed out your levels and taken all the damage resistance upgrades?  If not, you might need to stand further away in order to avoid getting hit.

Comment: Yep- I have. But even with the 'never die' cheat, Kwilanna still dies and I fail my mission.

Comment: Wait, so are you saying that the problem is actually that you and/or Kwilanna die by being too close to the generator when it explodes?